# iTunes Connect: How can I generate promo codes for Pro apps?

Tags: app-store-connect

I used to get an option to generate promo codes however since the new redesign which Apple did for the iTunes Connect, I haven't been able to find that option.

Where is it hidden?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tunes Connect has moved the location where the promo codes are generated.

To generate promo codes as of 10/22/2015 select the app -> Features -> Promo codes

Comment: Thank you very much Amber! Apple support is still stuck on 'Please send us the browser version, steps to reproduce this problem and what you had for breakfast last week' before we can proceed :P